# What are the average raw scores, and standard deviations for the WAIS-IV subtests?

Tags: measurement, intelligence, test

What are the average *raw* scores, and standard deviations for the WAIS-IV subtests (scores are normalized)?
For example, the digit symbol task gives you 120 seconds to substitute as many digits for symbols, given a key. What would the average person score *in terms of number of symbols completed*?

Comment: I imagine the information you are after would be in the WAIS IV scoring manual. Many university schools of psychology should have a copy.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim sounds like a cop out to an actual answer.

Comment: @caseyr547 That's why it is a comment. It also embodies the point that if you are using a test, ethically you should understand how to use the test, and that involves reading the test manual.

Comment: Why such the strong phobia to releasing this information online somewhere? No university prof's website did that? Or is there stiff legal action?